How would i create a hair material with a light streak effect on them?
im trying to make a light streak from a hair mesh, i tried faking it using a plane and some curves but it just does not look right. im trying to make a random light streak down the hair particle but what i got was a  lightshow.
here is what i got

and here is the effect i want to achieve

i want to try and make it in geometry node but im still not confident enough to use it.
